# Getting Time Interval from Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Timezone and the data looks like:

```
Call_ID        Start_Time
93856          2011-08-04 09:59:47.000
58796          2011-08-05 14:54:37.000
25489          2011-08-09 15:32:13.000
```

I want the output as :

```
Call_ID        Start_Time                    Interval
93856          2011-08-04 09:59:47.000       0930
58796          2011-08-05 14:54:37.000       1430
25489          2011-08-09 15:32:13.000       1530
```

I did something like this:

```
Select  Call_ID , Start_Time,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(minute,Start_Time)>30 THEN 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,Start_Time) AS VARCHAR),2) + '30'          
ELSE 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,Start_Time) AS VARCHAR),2) + '00'        
END
From Timezone
Group By Call_ID , Start_Time,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(minute,Start_Time)>30 THEN 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,Start_Time) AS VARCHAR),2) + '30'          
ELSE 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,Start_Time) AS VARCHAR),2) + '00'        
END
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Call_ID,
       Start_Time,
       right(100+datepart(hour, Start_Time), 2)+
       right(100+30*(datepart(minute, Start_Time)/30), 2) as Interval
from TimeZone
```

Comment: +1, very much like what I was thinking, only you should first divide by 30, then multiply by 30 (in this case the order matters).

Comment: Also I was thinking about calculating the numeric value of `Interval` as a single value, something like this: `RIGHT(10000 + DATEPART(HOUR, Start_Time) * 100 + DATEPART(HOUR, Start_Time) / 30 * 30, 2)`, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Andriy M - Thanks, I threw in an unnecessary cast where it is enough with some parenthesis.

Comment: @Andriy M - Your version hmmm slightly modified `RIGHT(10000 + DATEPART(HOUR, Start_Time) * 100 + DATEPART(MINUTE, Start_Time) / 30 * 30, 4)`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I simply overlooked that CAST. (Can't imagine how that could happen.) I can see now that you are using parentheses (with or without CAST) to show the order of calculations explicitly. Everything's all right then, thank you.

Comment: Yes, MINUTE, of course, that's what I meant (forgot to replace after copypasting), and `4` instead of `2`, you are right again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really any shorter, but certainly tidier with far less casts and string concatenation:

```
;WITH intervals(h) AS
(
  SELECT TOP (48) CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(MINUTE, 30*(number), '00:00'))
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE number >= 0
    GROUP BY number
    ORDER BY number
)
SELECT
  t.Call_ID,
  t.Start_Time,
  Interval = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), i.h), ':', '')
FROM intervals AS i
INNER JOIN dbo.TimeZone AS t
ON DATEDIFF(MINUTE, i.h, CONVERT(TIME(0), t.Start_Time)) BETWEEN 1 AND 30;
```

Not sure what you wanted to do if you have a value right on the boundary. Do you want it to fall in the current interval or the previous? You can change `BETWEEN 1 AND 30` to `BETWEEN 0 AND 29` if you want different behavior.